# Permission denied when using ssh to access server

Tags: linux, ssh, mac

I'm new to Linux and I tried to access my new ads server via `ssh`, like

`ssh sjc-ads-6547`

And I entered my password but it said,

`Permission denied, please try again.`

My password is right and I've tried to set the `PasswordAuthentication` and `PermitRootLogin` parameter to `yes`, and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. But it's still not working. Just wonder where went wrong.

I kept getting this,

```
yuxuanli@sjc-ads-6547's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

yuxuanli@sjc-ads-6547's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

yuxuanli@sjc-ads-6547's password: 
yuxuanli@sjc-ads-6547: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -vvv user@host` and the access logs of your server to your question.

Comment: General FYI: Logging into SSH with a passphrase is insecure - instead, it's recommended to create an encrypted [passphrase protected] SSH key, using that for login and disabling password logins _(if you have a hardware key, such as a YubiKey, you can store your SSH key in it's A[uthorization] key slot)_

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/auth*` if you see few logs wrt., to the user?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the remote username if it is different from your local username as following:

`ssh remoteusername@remotehost`

Comment: I tried. But I think it's the same..